# Flipping a vector across the y-axis

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have a vector A=[2,2] and I want to express it as [-2,2] (pretending I don´t know the coordinates). Notice that this is the same vector flipped over the y axis...How do I do this?

A negative vector simply turns it around...

Comment: Well $\alpha(x,y)=(-x,y)$ is the linear map that does this but I'm not sure if that's what you are asking for here…

Comment: No this is just really basic vector operations. I´m not even sure what a linear map is. It's as simple as stated in the question. A vector [2,2] when flipped over the y-axis is [2,-2]. I want to express any vector AB in such a way.

Comment: What do you mean by "express it as [-2,2]"?

Comment: If I don't know the coordinates of my vector and the vector is just AB. I want an operation that does the exact same thing as my ''flip'' example. For example:

If AB is a vector, then -1*AB is a vector in opposite direction.

I want:

If AB is a vector, then (SomeMaths)AB is a vector flipped across the y-axis.

Comment: Simple picture for clarification: http://imgur.com/GecrxgA

(Pretend both vectors start at the origin and have the same length)

Comment: Another way of explaining this is: I want to mirror the vector AB across the y axis..?

Comment: Well, $\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 0\\
  0 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}$ would do the trick if you knew matrix multiplication. Otherwise you can always subtract $(4,0)$ but that's hardly an interesting solution.

Comment: I know matrix multiplication but I don't have a matrix...I just want to rotate my vector by 90 degrees.

I didn't realize that was so hard so perhaps I am attacking the problem from the wrong angle. My problem is:

Consider this hexagon and pretend it is perfect. http://imgur.com/bCrxgdc

Now I want to express the vector CB in terms of OA and OB.

My thought was to take OB and ''flip'' it and then take OB+Flipped OB and that would result in CB..

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to make this clear. There is no number $t$ such that $t(x,y)=(-x,y)$. If you want to use only addition/subtraction/multiplication by scalar your only solution is to take $(x,y)$ and subtract $(2x,0)$ from it.

The good solution is to use the linear map $\alpha : \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2:(x,y)\rightarrow(-x,y)$. Associated with this linear map is the matrix I posted in comments :

$$\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 0\\
  0 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}$$

I won't explain here why this is the matrix of $\alpha$ but now if you use basic matrix multiplication :

$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}ax+by\\ cx+dy\end{pmatrix}$$

You will get :

$$\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}2\\ 2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$$

Anyway, this is how you do it, I hate giving methods like this without explanation but you should take a linear algebra class or read a book about linear algebra to really understand what's going on here. Keep in mind that this is very basic linear algebra and you will come across this type of thing very quickly in any introductory book/class.

Answer (score 1):

Your question mentions "the y-axis", and this implies that you have already chosen a coordinate system that you're going to use to express vectors. So any (simple) answer is going to involve some mention of coordinates, too. There isn't going to be a "coordinate free" answer like there is for reversing (negating) a vector.

The answer was already given in one of the comments: the "reflection" of the vector $(x,y)$ is the vector $(-x,y)$.

The answer to your hexagon question is $CB=OA$.

Comment: And if I don't know the coordinates? What if the vector is just explained as 'A'? Is there no general function on a vector that flips it? -1 * A would result in the y value being negative as well. How do I avoid this with binary operations?

Comment: As I said, the answer has to involve coordinates because the question does (it talks about the y-axis). I can tell you how to reflect in an arbitrary line that's given without any reference to coordinates, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Do you know about dot and cross products of vectors?

Comment: Never mind. We don't need dot and cross products to answer your hexagon question. See the last paragraph of my answer.